# VBA to word arrow bullet

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to format the bullets to get the arrow formatted bullet point. I'm just using this short piece to format.

```
.range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault
```

This is what is desired. 
[image]

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: I want the arrow formated bullet points but the code only gives me the circular default

Comment: If you don't want the default bullet format then I think you need to use: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.listformat.applylisttemplate(v=office.14).aspx